# Why JPA Repository always create a transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

When I use P6Spy to capture SQL statements, I found there always a commit action takes about 200ms, which means there is always a transaction.

After more research, I found JPA always creates a transaction.

1. JPA always create a transaction even for **findById** method.
2. JPA always create a transaction even when explicitly annotate a method with "@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.**NEVER**)".

The root cause is **SimpleJpaRepository** class is annotated with **@Transactional**, and the
default propagation is **REQUIRED**.

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID>
```

SimpleJpaRepository seems so obsessed with transaction...

Question:

1. Why SimpleJpaRepository add  @Transactional at class level? The deleteById and delete method already annotated with @Transactional right?
2. How to avoid transaction for JPA query like findById?

When I hack Spring JPA source code like below, and recompiled as a home-made jar to replace the canonical jar, now JPA queries work like a charm, and for queries the commit is gone!

```
//Hack!
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID>
```

P.S.
Related spring source codes here:
TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.RepositoryAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource

**Edit:**
JPA Transaction here means JpaTransactionManager hold a physical connection with **setAutoCommit(false)** and follows with a commit action in the end.

Comment: In JDBC everything happens in a transaction, but without an explicit `@Transactional`, you're likely relying on auto-commit behaviour of the driver.

Comment: Perhaps i didn't make my question clear.  JDBC query won't likely happen in a transaction. A transaction is a connection with auto commit set to false and a commit/rollback in the end. I've edited the quetion to make it clear.

Comment: Did you try the same with auto-commit enabled and saw that this mode is faster? I think `NEVER` actually means that an exception will be thrown if the method is called from within a TX. `SUPPORTS` shouldn't start a transaction though. Could you try to trace where the commit comes from? Maybe you should clear your persistence context after the load action to avoid auto-flushing which might involve a commit.